# How to specify filename with extension using AWS S3 presigned post?

Tags: javascript, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

referring to this:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/PresignedPost.html

When having users upload directly to S3 from browser. You can specify the URL that user must post the resource to.

You can also use ${filename} to have the path based on the file name of the object in question.

However, we just want the file type rather than the full name because we want a predicable location on the resource.

for example, we want the url to be /folder/1234.png rather than /folder/mypic.png  after the user uploads a file called mypic.png.

To be clear, if we specify /folder/1234 then the png extension is lost.   The file type could be any image.

Since we don't know the file extension it seems like the only way to get it is through ${filename}

Is there some other type of template type variable like ${filetype}?

Any other solutions?

Comment: It's a bit unclear who's generating the presigned URL, your client or your server. If it's the server, when the client sends a filename, your server can use any string handling technique to replace the basename of the provided filename with your generated ID, keep the extension, and create a presigned URL to return to the client. The client then interacts with the presigned URL.

Answer (score 2):

First, the link you provided is the SDK for Ruby v1, which is very outdated. I would recommend the [v3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html) instead. As you will see, these docs suggest you do not need to construct a PresignedPost yourself and should try out the [Bucket#presigned_post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#presigned_post-instance_method) and [Object#presigned_post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#presigned_post-instance_method) first.

When you create the request for a pre-signed URL, simply use your desired key. For example, if the user uploads `bar/foo.png`, your Ruby code would create a pre-signed URL for a new object called `bar/1234.png`. Instead of `1234` I would recommend a uuid, timestamp, or equivalent to ensure object names are unique and don't overwrite eachother.

For example:

```
# Assuming you already have an S3 client instance configured
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: "us-east-1")
s3_bucket_name = 'foo'
s3_bucket = s3.bucket(s3_bucket_name)
file_name = 'bar/foo.png'
new_key = create_new_key(file_name)
presigned_post = s3_bucket.presigned_post(
  key: new_key
)
```

In `create_new_key()` you would put logic needed to manipulate the string of the original file path to the desired key. I would advise using Ruby's `File` built-in to accomplish this most efficiently.